# Yii2 Load Controller

Tags: yii2

I created one controller `SlideController` for manage the slide on my website.
But In the `SiteController` I just want to load some action in the `SlideController`.
Is it possible or not? If it's possible ,how can I?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

The proper way I think, is to create `yii2\base\Action` subclasses which contain common actions shared by different controller.

As a reference on how to write `Action` and how controller links up it, you can read the source code here - https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/tree/master/framework/rest

Comment: Sorry , I'm really don't understand what it is. Could you give any example?

Comment: Basically, there are two ways to define *action* in controller, one is declaring `actionXXX()` method (where XXX is the name of the action), another one is returning an array of "action name-value pair" under `actions()` method. For the second way, examples are inside the link above. Read `ActiveController` and `xxxAction` classes.

Comment: I know how to create an action , but I don't know how can I access that action from others controller?

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem. If you can make ControllerA to access ActionA, why can't you make ControllerB to access ActionA too?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for your need:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30432980/748156

In your case, in SiteController, set it like:

```
Yii::$app->runAction('slide/action', ['param1'=>'value1', 'param2'=>'value2']);
```